# PDF::API2 image_png

Tags: image, perl, pdf-generation

I have a problem with pdf::api2 I need to edit an existing pdf and put in some images. The problem is that for inserting 4 images it takes around 20 seconds per image. So the whole process goes up to minute and a half. Is there some magic i can do to speed up the process? The images are 1920 × 1080 and need to stay that size, because i need quality pdf-s... So without further ado, here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use PDF::API2;
print "start ".(localtime)."\n";
$pdf = PDF::API2->open("sample.pdf"); 
$page = $pdf->openpage(1); 
$page->mediabox(840,600) 
$gfx=$page->gfx; 
print "first image ".(localtime)."\n"; 
$first=$pdf->image_png("first.png"); 
print "inserting first image ".(localtime)."\n"; 
$gfx->image($first,134,106,510,281); 
print "saving ".(localtime)." \n"; 
$pdf->saveas('new_file.pdf'); 
print "done ".(localtime)." \n";
```

The output i get:

```
start Mon Jun 3 10:46:31 2013 
first image Mon Jun 3 10:46:31 2013 
inserting first image Mon Jun 3 10:46:53 2013 
saving Mon Jun 3 10:46:53 2013 
done Mon Jun 3 10:46:57 2013
```

So the most time consuming process is image_png which takes 22 seconds in this example... Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

**Update:** if i use the same image converted to JPEG, it works flawlessly, under a second. The problem is i need the transparency of the PNG files

Comment: Update: if i use the same image converted to JPEG, it works flawlessly, under a second. The problem is i need the transparency of the PNG files

Comment: As a start, you should `use strict` and `use warnings`. I assume the `use PDF::API2` line is not on the same line as the shebang. To get a more sophisticated timing of this, take a look at http://p3rl.org/Devel::NYTProf. It can help you figure out where it is slowing down.

Comment: I added your comment to the question. You can also do that yourself by clicking the [edit] link.

Comment: Thanks, i fixed the use PDF::API2 line... As for the slow down, you think this NYTProf can help with the API2 slowdowns? I mean, the slowdown is $first=$pdf->image_png("first.png"); if i use another function for image processing it works fast

Comment: I think it will help you track down what really is the problem. It will not fix it. But maybe you figure out what the problem is and can write a fix for it yourself. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for PDF::API2 explicitly says that operations on transparent .png files are slow, and recommends installing PDF::API2::XS or (IIRC) Image::PNG::libpng to speed it up.